# Javascript array variable as "name" not working

Tags: javascript

I've a javascript variable and running it in my firefox console.

```
var name = ['manish','google'];
alert(name[0]);
```

The result of above alert is `m`

But If rewrite the code as below

```
var names = ['manish','google'];
alert(names[0]);
```

Then it alerts `manish`

Can anyone please let me know that what is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

`name` is a property of the `window` object. [Check this out](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_name.asp)

`console.log(name);` shows that `name` is recognized as a `String` not an `Array`.

Console Output:

> manish,google

Use a different variable name if you are in the global scope...

Comment: `var` overrules that though. Does it not?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol — Not when you're in the global scope

Comment: @Quentin Then this answer is incomplete ;) After all, when I run the code in my IE11 console, it works just fine, presumably because it uses a different scope.

Comment: @Quentin Then why this works fine? var innerHeight = ['manish','google'];alert(innerHeight[0])

Comment: innerHeight is also a property of window object. Isn't it??

Comment: `innerHeight` doesn't have a setter function defined behind the scenes to do special stuff when you set it.

Comment: You mean to say, it is restricted to reconfigure with configurable descriptor?